# Fastest way to load (and cache) Kendo UI CSS and JS files

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, xpages

I am integrating some really great Kendo UI components into a web site built on Xpages (and using Bootstrap). Loading for most things seems pretty fast, except for some of the css and js files from Kendo UI.

I have three methods to load the files:

1. Use a CDN
2. Load them on the Domino Server and point to them
3. Load them into the db and point to them

I want to use the most efficient method of doing this. My guess is it is best to load them on the server.

As the user goes from page to page in my application, will the files be cached, so they don't have to load them again and again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My little favorite these days is to "hide" Domino behind an nginx. All my static resources get delivered by directories on the nginx which I keep in sync using rsync. 
I compiled the mod_pagespeed into nginx which accelerates things further.

Another option is to use a gulp workflow to combine all CSS and JS into one file and compress that one. Add expiry headers. Works on plain Domino or Nginx

Answer (score 1):

CDN's seem good but could be blocked from various companies.  I've seen this.  So unless this is an internal app I'd steer clear from that.

Putting them on the server is likely the fastest but then it becomes problematic if multiple servers are used.  Keeping them in sync and everything.

The best thing you could do I think is put them into an OSGI library and load that on your server.  That's fairly advanced though. But I THINK you could tie into the CSS/JS aggregator but I'm not positive about that.

So barring that I'd put them into the db and I'd expect them to be cached from the local browser.

Comment: The resources are only cached if told so :-) This can be done with internet site rules and/or with the "Custom Browser Cache Expiration" in Application Properties